# facebook like button doesnt show faces for FB pages

Tags: facebook-like, fbml, facebook-likebox

I have a website where I want to show a facebook like button, which shows the faces.

my FBML looks like this

```
<fb:like send="false" width="200" show_faces="true" action="like" href="http://www.facebook.com/my-page" colorscheme="lite"></fb:like>
```

this doesnt show the faces, but if I add a url which is not a FB one, something like 
http://mysite.com/somepage/

it shows the faces

any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, I think I found the answer after some troubleshooting.  The faces will only show for a URL that you either like or you have friends that like it.

Answer (score -3):

Try this in your code and let me know if that works for you --

```
show-faces="true"
```

OR

```
data-show-faces="true"
```

Comment: this cant be the issue really, case when i try this with a url like http://mysite.com/somepage/ it works